# Using Generic Type Parameter classes

Tags: java, android

I have the following class in my code

```
public class GenericService<E> extends  SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<E> {
    public GenericService(Class<E> clazz) {
        super(clazz);

    }
    @Override
    public E loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now the constructor for this class takes a Argument of type class. i want to remove this parameter, and directly say something like super(E.class) ? But this is given my an error. So if i GenericService loginService=new GenericService 
that constructor should call super with the params Login.class. This works like this but not the generic way by saying E.class. How can i do this ?

## EDIT

I want to merge the following classes into a single clas

public class LoginService extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest {

```
private Login.Request loginRequest;
private final String loginRequestURL = "/login";

public LoginService() {
    super(Login.Response.class);
}

public final Login.Response loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {

    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri.parse(
            ProfileInfo.getActiveProfile().getbaseURL() + loginRequestURL)
            .buildUpon();
    String url = uriBuilder.build().toString();

    return getRestTemplate().postForObject(url, loginRequest,
            Login.Response.class);
}

@Override
public final String createCacheKey() {
    return loginRequest.getUsername() + "" + loginRequest.getPassword();
}
```

}

and

```
public class ForgetPasswordService extends
            SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<ForgetPassword.Response> {

        private final String forgotPasswordURL = "/forgotpassword";

        public ForgetPasswordService() {
            super(ForgetPassword.Response.class);
        }

        public final ForgetPassword.Response loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {

            Uri.Builder uriBuilder = Uri
                    .parse(ProfileInfo.getActiveProfile().getbaseURL()
                            + forgotPasswordURL).buildUpon();
            String url = uriBuilder.build().toString();
            return getRestTemplate().postForObject(url, forgotPasswordRequest,
                    ForgetPassword.Response.class);
        }

        public final String createCacheKey() {
            return forgotPasswordRequest.getPhoneOrEmailAddress();
        }

    }
```

Both classes are identicle. The only difference between is the type of response they are given out. Now i have about 23 of these classes. Really abad idea adding all of these classes if they are not needed.

Kind Regards

Comment: You seem to be trying to do something that can better be done in a different way: I had a quick look at the definition of SpringAndroidSpiceRequest, and the loadDataFromNetwork seems to be the only method that does anything. What are you trying to achieve by overriding that to return null?

Comment: This is just a test. All of requests are differnt POJO classes. I want to have a single request class and not multiple classes. That why i want to make a generic request class. Does this make sense ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't because of  Type Erasure. None of the details of which class you used as the type parameter makes it into the runtime class. This is a limitation of Java Generics

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: So how could i make a no argument constructor for my class ?

Comment: @user1730789 You cannot make a no-argument constructor *and* keep your class generic at the same time.

Comment: There goes dependency Injection :(

Comment: +1 but I think I'll keep this answer in a file, ready to use the next time this question comes up, which is roughly once per day :/

Comment: It is not only about type erasure, but conceptual as well. Try to answer this question: when you use the no-argument constructor, which class would you like the SpringAndroidSpiceRequest to use?

Comment: The one that is bound to E ?

Answer (score 0):

> There goes dependency Injection :(

Either find a way to pass the class object, e.g. something like

```
<constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class" value="com.mycompany.Foo"/>
```

(I'm not sure if this is  correct in Spring)

or create a subclass:

```
public class FooService extends GenericService<Foo>{
    public FooService() {
        super(Foo.class);
    }
}
```